# Play Framework - convert form errors for flash messaging

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to convert form errors for passing them to a flash message. How can I do it?

Here is the code where I want to convert them:

```
newDb.fold(
    hasErrors = { form =>
      // here I want to translate errors to string for Flash messaging
      Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing("error" -> Messages("msg.new.validation.errors"))
    },
    success = { dbToInsert =>
      MyDatabases.insert(dbToInsert)
      val message = Messages("msg.new.success", dbToInsert.name)
      Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing("success" -> message)
    }
  )
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
def convert(text: String, messages: Seq[FormError]): String =
  """<div class="alert" role="alert">""" + text + formatMessages(messages) + "</div>"

private def formatMessages(messages: Seq[FormError]): String = {
    if(messages.size > 0){ 
      "<ul>" + messages.foldLeft("")((res,message) => res + "<li>" + message.message + "</li>") + "</ul>"
    } else ""
}
```

Then use your flashing message as follows:

```
@Html(flash.get("error").getOrElse("Welcome!"))
```

Then style the message with *CSS* as you would do normally. You can use this `convert` method to create success and error flashings with different colors by adding a class to the `div` tag.

Comment: Thank you @Peter, it is exactly what I'm searching for

Answer (score 0):

How you convert them depends on in what format you want them of course, but you can find them in `Form.errors` on your `hasErrors` form instance. `Form.errors` is a sequence of `FormError` where each of them has got the field `key` that caused the error, `messages` that is the error message I18N keys or actual messages and `args` that is values to interpolate into the messages.

To convert them to human readable strings you could take a look at how it is done by the play template form helpers in `views.html.helper.FieldElements.errors` method: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/Helpers.scala#L26

Comment: Thanks @johanandren, but I want to convert them before the template and I need them in a String, because Flash message handle only String variables.

Comment: Yeah, so you will have to use that data to make a string that suits your needs. Nothing for free I'm afraid.